# Cannot connect gRPC Java Client with gRPC .NET server

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-dotnet

My gRPC server is implemented in ASP.NET 7 in the following way:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLogging(c => c.ClearProviders());
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterImpl>();

Console.WriteLine($"Server started at port 50051");
app.Run($"https://localhost:50051");

class GreeterImpl : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
  public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message from {request.Name}: {request.Message}");
    return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply { Message = $"Hello {request.Name} from .NET server" });
  }
}
```

I use the NuGet package *Grpc.AspNetCore*. The .NET Client needs no certificate and works without any problems.

I have tried to implement a Java Client, basically in the following way:

```java
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", PORT)
                            // .usePlaintext()      // (1)
                           .useTransportSecurity()  // (2)
                           .build();
try {
  GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub blockingClient = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

  HelloRequest request = HelloRequest.newBuilder()
                                     .setName("Java client")
                                     .setMessage("My message")
                                     .build();
  HelloReply reply = blockingClient.sayHello(request);
} 
catch(StatusRuntimeException ex) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I create the `ManagedChannel` using `usePlaintext`, I get the exception: `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason`

Using `useTransportSecurity` results in the following exception:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem`

*Question 1:* How do I have to implement the Java client that can connect to the .NET server?

*Question 2:* How must the .NET server be modified so that it supports plain text communication?